# powering up the arduino and gsm shield module

Tags: arduino, voltage, dc, amperage, gsm

i am just wondering if what i am thinking is safe for my modules. I want to power up my arduino x which rated at 5vdc/1A and my gsm module rated 5-9vdc/1.5A, using my bandspeed adapter that has an output of 5vdc/2.6A. What I will do is power up my arduino using the adapter and i will tap a parallel connection to the gsm module so that both are powered up. Is it safe? will the current change etc. Give me anexplanation. Please help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Safe if >>**

Yes it is safe. You have mentioned like 5-9vdc for GSM Module. Usually 
GSM module powered by on board voltage Regulator. So, i am guessing in your GSM board also having the voltage regulator which will take care of Constant Voltage.

And also check your power supply whether it can able to provide 2.5A(1A+1.5A) with constant 5V. If there is no drop mean  no problem you can go ahead with this.

**Not safe if >>**

Some Power supplies voltage may drop to some certain level if you load to its full capacity. So check for the voltage drop at full load. If voltage drops for more than 0.7 obviously you can't use that power supply.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I use 5amp adapter, will it also be safe? ALso I have a 9vdc/1amp adapter, which is better?

Comment: Yes, you can use 5 amp adapter. It may not get voltage drop at 2.5A. (50%of load). Better use this adapter with 3A fuse.